# How to assign python groupby results to columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data "last_3_days" like this:

[image]

Then I groupby `['user_id','sku_id','type']` and count the number of each 'type' of each `['user_id','sku_id']` pair.

How can I assign the groupby results to each `['user_id','sku_id']` pair? For each `['user_id','sku_id']` pair, they should have these additional columns:`['type1_count','type2_count',...,'type6_count']`.
Each column means the count of that 'type'. There are 6 types in the 'type' column.

*Update*:
@gereleth's answer is what I want. But the result is like this:

[image]

How to change the above to this?

[image]

Comment: It's considered bad form to put pictures up on posts.  In order to facilitate helping, we like to have easy access to producing a working set of data.  I can't copy paste your image.  That said, we could care less if you post an image if you **also** have code or text to produce the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `unstack` on the groupby results.

```
df = (last_౩_days.groupby('user_id', 'sku_id','type')
        .size().unstack(fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('type').add_suffix('count'))
```

Unstack will turn the last level of index into columns. `fill_value` is the value to use for missing combinations. The names of new columns will be the unique values of type, so the last line renames them into the format you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But the result is a little different from what I want. I have a update on the question description. Please take a look. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just add a `.reset_index()` at the end.